# Check if some elements are missing and some are not python

Tags: python

I have a list of animal names:

```
aList = [animal_lionAnimal, 
animal_elephantAnimal_1, 
animal_elephantAnimal_2,
animal_elephantAnimal_3,
animal_pandaAnimal_1,
animal_pandaAnimal_2]
```

Then I have a file which also contains these animal names. I read the file by argumentparser and then use regex to find these animals (more specifically re.finall).

```
for aFile in args.filePath:
    contents = open(aFile ).read()

# An example of what the regex tries find in the file: (*animal_elephantAnimal_1()) = 0.0; # some comments
aRegex = re.findall(r'(?:.\s+\(\*)(animal\w+)(?:.[^;]*)', contents)
```

What I want to do is a "verification" to see if the animals from aList are in the file. Here are some scenarios:

1. If all animals from aList are found then its OK
2. If all animals from aList are missing then its still OK
3. If some animals from aList are missing and some are not (e.g. lion exist but not panda and elephant) then its NOT OK and should give a `sys.exit` or something else.

Here are my statements so far:

```
#Remove matching animals
listHaveElement = list(set(aList) - set(aRegex))

if not listHaveElement: #if list is []
    print "There are no animals name missing ", listHaveElement
else: #if there are animals missing
    print sys.exit("There are animals missing and they are: {0}".format(listHaveElement))
```

Some example:

```
animal_lionAnimalAsdf, -> Missing due to wrong name 

animal_elephantAnimal_1, -> not missing  

animal_elephantAnimal_2, -> not missing 

animal_elephantAnimal_3, -> not missing 

animal_pandaAnimal_1Mooo, -> missing due to wrong name 

animal_pandaAnimal_2 -> not missing
```

Don't know how to solve the 3rd statement.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you can check if all elements of list `A` are contained within list `B` by the following:

```
all(a in B for a in A)
```

This will return `True` if each element of `A` is within `B` or if `A` is empty.  It will return `False` if any single element is missing in `A`.  Therefore, you can use:

```
if all(animal in aRegex for animal in aList):
    print "There are no animals name missing ", aList
else:
    listHaveElement = list(set(aList) - set(aRegex))
    print sys.exit("There are animals missing and they are: {0}".format(listHaveElement))
```

Comment: Hmm. But if all of them are missing/spelled wrong in the file then it should not "crash" since it is OK. Because either all the animal names are there or none of them are. It can't be half are there and half are not.. But it feels like it that solution is not doable since I am comparing a list with a file?

Comment: @gants If both `aRegex` and `aList` are lists (which based on your question they should be), then this approach will work.  If that is not the case, please revise your question to clarify what each variable is